# Is it a risk to keep ios 6 on iPhone 4?

Tags: ios

After recently found risk for ios 7 device and releasing an update to resolve it, is it a risk to keep ios 6 on iPhone 4?

Comment: I can't give you a full answer, but yes, it is.

Comment: "Is it a risk to run out dated software that's no longer really supported" ... well ...

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,** there is a risk because you're using unsupported software which is never recommended. [That's the reason why Apple gave out iOS 6.1.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6146)

One of them is **the SSL leak** which is fixed in iOS 7.0.6 and iOS 6.1.6

However, you can also install the SSL-fix by Jailbreaking your device (if you did not do this yet). You can use [this guide](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/02/fix-ssl-bug-without-upgrading-ios-7-0-6-ios-6-1-6.html).

*Sidenote: If you have an iPhone 4 and not a 4s, as stated in your question I'd use the Jailbreak Fix. iOS 7 killed my iPhone 4. It's too slow.*

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a known vulnerability and Apple [won't let you update your iPhone 4 to 6.1.6](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122039/is-it-possible-to-update-any-ios-6-device-to-ios-6-1-6/122150#122150) (yet) It is impossible to say there is no risk.

So yes there are some risk.